# Rolling two dice...

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, dice, multinomial-coefficients

Let $A_n$ be the number of fives, $B_n$ the number of sixes and $C_n$ the number of eights in $n$ rolls of two dices. For which n do we have:
$E(A_n) < E(min(B_n,C_n))$ ?

Comment: $E[5]=$ "the expected number of $5$'s in a double series of $n$ rolls both". Is that correct? But what is exactly $E[\min(6,8)]$?

Comment: Interesting question, a bit "different."  To clarify, let $X_n$ be the number of $6$'s in $n$ rolls, let $Y_n$ be the number of $8$'s, and let $W_n=\min(X_n.Y_n)$. We want  to know the values of $n$ for which $E(W_n)\gt \frac{4n}{36}$. I hope it will not be closed, but fear it will be.

Comment: It is likely to be closed anyway, unless I invent "work."

Comment: @andre you could be right. This practice is the death of many interesting questions.

Comment: The value of $min(B_n,C_n)$ can probably be calculated only with "brute force".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean with E(5) and E(min(6,8)) but probably you can find the expectation by using the whole table with probabilities of throwing a sum, so if you define X to be the sum of the two dices then P(X=2)=1/36, P(X=3)=2/36,... and if you need a certain combination of dices with the E(.) as definition, just make a table with all combinations.

Answer (score 0):

I run a program with PARI/GP :

```
? n=0;gef=0;while(gef==0,s=0;su=0;n=n+1;for(a=0,n,for(b=0,n,for(c=0,n,for(d=0,n,
if(a+b+c+d==n,su=su+n!/a!/b!/c!/d!*p1^a*p2^b*p3^c*p4^d*min(b,c);s=s+n!/a!/b!/c!/
d!*p1^a*p2^b*p3^c*p4^d)))));if(su>n/9,gef=1);print(n,"    ",s,"  ",su*1.0,"    "
,n/9*1.0,"      ",(su-n/9)*1.0))
```

The end of the output is

```
57    1  6.338345777056660390204361588    6.333333333333333333333333333      0.0
05012443723327056871028254579
```

So, the answer should be $n=57$.

Comment: Did you take into account that two dices are rolled?

Comment: Yes, I used the probabilities $p_1=1/9$, $p_2=p_3=5/36$ , $p_4=11/18$